# Why the last empty row has been pulled as an additional test with null values in selenium apache POI

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I have four rows in an excel, first row is for the heading and rest of the three rows has values in it. I have entered the code in a way to avoid the header and read the rows which contains values only. However instead of fetching only three rows it comes with one additional null value rows as below, Why it is fetching the null values did I miss anything? Find the code and error message.

**Message**

> PASSED: testShipment("Mumbai", "New York", "18000", "10000", "20000")
>
> PASSED: testShipment("Mumbai", "Cochin", "2000", "30000", "5000")
>
> PASSED: testShipment("Cochin", "Farah", "16000", "18000", "19000")
>
> FAILED: testShipment(null, null, null, null, null)

**Code**

```
int TotalCol = sh.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
    int Totalrows = sh.getLastRowNum()+1;
    String[][] data = new String[Totalrows][TotalCol];

    DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter(); // creating formatter using the default locale

    for (int i = 1; i < Totalrows; i++) {
        Row r = sh.getRow(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < TotalCol; j++) {
            Cell c = r.getCell(j);
            try {
                if (c.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {

                    String j_username = formatter.formatCellValue(c);
                    data[i][j] = j_username;
                    System.out.println("data[i][j]" + data[i][j]);
                } else {
                    data[i][j] = String.valueOf(c.getNumericCellValue());
                    String j_username = formatter.formatCellValue(c);
                    data[i][j] = j_username;
                    System.out.println("data[i][j] numeric val" + data[i][j]);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: could you share the code?

Comment: @Ashokkumar Sure, added in the question area.

Comment: @Jagadeesh Try by removing the + 1 one from sh.getLastRowNum()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that works, thanks to everyone for helping on this!

```
int TotalCol = sh.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
    int Totalrows = sh.getLastRowNum()+1;
//Entering minus one(-1) during data declaration ignores the first row as first row is a header
    String[][] data = new String[Totalrows-1][TotalCol];

    DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter(); // creating formatter using the default locale

    for (int i = 1; i <Totalrows; i++) {
        Row r = sh.getRow(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < TotalCol; j++) {
            Cell c = r.getCell(j);
            try {
                if (c.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {

                    String j_username = formatter.formatCellValue(c);
//Adding minus on(data[i-1]) helps to read the first cell which is (0,1), in this case (0,1) would not read the header since we have skipping the header from the table in the previous step on top, therefore the actual table starts from the second row.
                    data[i-1][j] = j_username;
                    System.out.println("data[i-1][j]" + data[i-1][j]);
                } else {
                    data[i-1][j] = String.valueOf(c.getNumericCellValue());
                    String j_username = formatter.formatCellValue(c);
                    data[i-1][j] = j_username;
                    System.out.println("data[i-1][j] numeric val" + data[i-1][j]);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

"

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below code like checking null condition

```
for (int k = 1; k <= totalRows; k++) {
    String testCaseID = sheet.getRow(k).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();

    if (testCaseID.equalsIgnoreCase(tcID)) {

        for (int l = 1; l < totalCols; l++) {

            String testData_FieldName = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(l).getStringCellValue();

            if (testData_FieldName.equalsIgnoreCase(header)) {
                cell = sheet.getRow(k).getCell(l);
                if (cell != null) {
                    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:// numeric value in excel
                        result = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                    break;

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING: // string value in excel
                        result = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        break;

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN: // boolean value in excel
                        result = cell.getBooleanCellValue();
                        break;

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK: // blank value in excel
                        result = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        break;

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR: // Error value in excel
                        result = cell.getErrorCellValue() + "";
                        break;

                    default:
                        throw new CustomException("The cell data type is invalid");
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        k = totalRows + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi , This change still gives me null error, this time it didnt pick my last row,
PASSED: testShipment("Mumbai", "New York", "18000", "10000", "20000")
PASSED: testShipment("Mumbai", "Cochin", "2000", "30000", "5000")
FAILED: testShipment(null, null, null, null, null)

Comment: Do I have to make some changes in the for loop?

Comment: Try to check with null condition before feeding/printing the data. Modified the answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to change either the data array declaration part or `Totalrows` calculation part. Currently, you have created 4 rows object and only 3 rows values are assigned and hence 4th row values are holding null value.

```
String[][] data = new String[Totalrows][TotalCol];
```

In your string array, you are not persisting the header value and storing only values. So, please modify your code with any one of the below options (I would suggest you to use option 1)

**Option 1:**
   Remove the +1 from Totalrows variable and add the equal condition in your first for loop

```
//Removed the +1
int Totalrows = sh.getLastRowNum();
String[][] data = new String[Totalrows][TotalCol];

DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter(); // creating formatter using the default locale

//Condition is modified as i <= Totalrows
for (int i = 1; i <= Totalrows; i++) {
```

**Option 2:**
 Change the data[][] declaration part

```
int Totalrows = sh.getLastRowNum()+1;
String[][] data = new String[Totalrows-1][TotalCol];
```

Comment: @Jagadeesh: Have you checked with the above options?

Comment: Hi @subburaj: it's not working, both option 1 and 2 ignores one row out of three and it still projects the null value to me, PASSED: testShipment("Mumbai", "New York", "18000", "10000", "20000")PASSED: testShipment("Mumbai", "Cochin", "2000", "30000", "5000")FAILED: testShipment(null, null, null, null, null)

Comment: it is not bringing null values only when I change i value from 1 to zero in the for loop, but in this case I should delete the header row, otherwise it is picking my header as an input

Comment: Found it!, it is working if I update all data[i][j] into data[i-1][j]